# Slight issue in my argument

Tags: abstract-algebra

We consider the following set subset of $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$  and consider that set with operation multiplication.

$S = \{[0],[2],[4],[6],[8]\}$. We can notice that in the Cayley-table that the element $[6]$ is the identity, but that set isn't a group since $[0]$ isn't invertible. In general any subset of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ will be not a group with respect to multiplication if class $[0]$ is there, But my question is do we consider the identity $[6]$ or identity $[1]$.

Comment: I think it is [6] right because [1] isn't even in our set if someone could verify this that would be great !

Comment: If an element doe not possess inverse then definitely the choice of identity is wrong. Neither can we call an element outside a set as identity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, $[6]$ is the identity. You need only determine that $[6]$ satisfies the required properties, ie, [6][x]=[x]=[x][6] for all $[x] \in S$, which I assume you have already done. As you say in your comment, $[1]$ isn't even in $S$ to begin with, so it cannot possibly be an identity element of $S$.

Answer (score 0):

[6] is the identity because it belongs to your set and satisfies: [6][2]=[12]=[2], [6][4]=[24]=[4], [6][6]=[36]=[6], [6][8]=[48]=[8], just as you said.